# Image upload in React-CKEditor-5 using Laravel

Tags: reactjs, laravel, file-upload, ckeditor5

I want to upload an image using CKEditor-5 in React.js
My codes in the front side:

```js
<CKEditor
editor={ClassicEditor}
data={`<p>${label} : ${placeholder}</p>`}
config={
    {
        ckfinder:{
            uploadUrl: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/upload/"
        }
    }
}
/>
```

And my codes in Laravel in "UploadController":

```js
$imgpath = Storage::disk('public')->put("images/uploads", $request->file('upload'));
return response()->json([
    'default' => "http://127.0.0.1:8000/".$imgpath,
]);
```

After selecting the image, the image is successfully saved in my desired path. But a failure message appears on the front side

Do I have to install a package in Laravel?
I do not know where I am wrong?

Comment: please let us see failure message

Answer (score 0):

You need to return the response in correct JSON format.

The correct Json response format would be:

```
{
  fileName: "FileName.jpg",
  uploaded: 1,
  url: "http://127.0.0.1:8000/".$imgpath
}
```